# Node.js read large files directory with find and head

Tags: node.js

In node.js I read files with a spawn of `find` instead of using `fs.readdir` that is much more slower:

```
scanDirStream: function (needle, params) {
            var options = {
                type: 'f',
                name: '*'
            };
            for (var attrname in params) { options[attrname] = params[attrname]; }
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var opt = [needle];
                for (var k in options) {
                    var v = options[k];
                    if (!Util.empty(v)) {
                        opt.push('-' + k);
                        opt.push(v);
                    }
                };
                var res = '';
                var find = spawn('find', opt)
                find.stdout.on('data', _data => {
                    var buff = Buffer.from(_data, 'utf-8').toString();
                    if (buff != '') res += buff;
                })
                find.stderr.on('data', error => {
                    return reject(Buffer.from(error, 'utf-8').toString());
                });
                find.on('close', (_) => {
                    data = res.split('\n');
                    data = data.slice(0, data.length - 1);
                    return resolve(data);
                });
            });
        }//scanDirStream
```

and you call it like

```
scanDirStream(path, { name: name }).then(files => console.log(files))
```

For huge directories I would furtherly improve it limiting the output of `find`, before returning the listing to Node.js, so using a pipe to `head` like:

```
find -type -f "*.mp3" | head -n 100
```

that it should be like

```
var head = spawn('head',['-n','100])
var find = spawn('find', opt)
head.stdin.pipe(find)
                find.stdout.on('data', _data => {
                    var buff = Buffer.from(_data, 'utf-8').toString();
                    if (buff != '') res += buff;
                })
                find.stderr.on('data', error => {
                    return reject(Buffer.from(error, 'utf-8').toString());
                });
                find.on('close', (_) => {
                    data = res.split('\n');
                    data = data.slice(0, data.length - 1);
                    return resolve(data);
                });
```

but the pipe does not work properly

Comment: when you say `fs.readdir` is slow, how many files were in the directory?

Comment: @Neverever we talk about thousand hundreds files at least. There is a known issue in node.js - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125592/node-fs-readdir-freezing-in-folders-with-too-many-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piping should go from `find.stdout` to `head.stdin`, and final output is coming out of `head.stdout`

So, the code should look like this:

```
find.stdout.pipe(head.stdin);
```

And attach the on `data` & `close` listener on `head`

```
head.stdout.on('data', ...);

head.on('close', ...);
```

For error handling, you could attach listener to both `find.stderr` and `head.stderr`, since error could occur from any/both of the two commands.

Comment: So thank you. It apparently works, but it seems it is not doing the `head -n N` when doing `var head = spawn('head',[ '-n', options.limit]);` - see here https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/6e479d6b1bb4990af649cf3308b8b3c2

Comment: what's the `opt` printed value? and is `head` printing all or none?

Comment: So the parameters of `find` are `opt=[ '/root/', '-type', 'f', '-name', '*.wav' ]` while the parameters of `head` are like `['-n','10']` to set the limit let's say to 10. I get the listing of files, but it seems the `| head` has not been applied, since I get all files, not the head.