# nodejs list huge directories hangs

Tags: node.js

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55923578/758836) approach to list directory with a huge number of files (10K and more...):

```
scanDirStream = (needle, params) => {
            var options = {
                // find -type
                type: 'f',
                // find -name
                name: '*',
                limit: 100
            };
            for (var attrname in params) { options[attrname] = params[attrname]; }
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var opt = [needle];
                for (var k in options) {
                    var v = options[k];
                    if (!Util.empty(v) && k != 'limit') {
                        opt.push('-' + k);
                        opt.push(v);
                    }
                };
                var res = '';
                var find = spawn('find', opt);
                var head = spawn('head',[ '-n', options.limit]);
                find.stdout.pipe(head.stdin);

                head.stdout.on('data', _data => {
                    var buff = Buffer.from(_data, 'utf-8').toString();
                    if (buff != '') res += buff;
                })
                find.stderr.on('data', error => {
                    return reject(Buffer.from(error, 'utf-8').toString());
                });
                head.stderr.on('data', error => {
                    return reject(Buffer.from(error, 'utf-8').toString());
                });
                head.on('close', (_) => {
                    data = res.split('\n');
                    data = data.slice(0, data.length - 1);
                    return resolve(data);
                });
            });
        }//scanDirStream
```

so I call it passing the directory path and the limit of files to list that will be passed to the `head -n` command, while the `find` command will list files with a specified name, calling it like

// contents of `test.js`

```
scanDirStream(mediaRoot, {
        name: "*.mp3",
        limit: 100
    })
        .then(res => {
            console.debug("files %d", res.length);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Supposed to have 10000 files in the current `mediaRoot`, what happens is

- using a value for `limit` < 10000 node.js main loop hangs: I get the console output, but the script run `node test.js` does not terminates.
- using a `limit` value >= 10000 it correctly lists the files and output and terminates the run.

To try it out, point to a directory with about `~8000-100000` files and run the `test.js` script, changing the `limit` value to `100` and then `10000`:

```
// this will hang node
scanDirStream(mediaRoot, {
        name: "*.mp3",
        limit: 100
    })
```

and

```
// this will not hang node
scanDirStream(mediaRoot, {
        name: "*.mp3",
        limit: 10000
    })
```

You can occasionally get this error as well:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:779:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Socket.onerror (_stream_readable.js:713:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:456:5)
    at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:40:7)
    at Socket._destroy (net.js:604:3)
    at Socket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:32:8)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:781:10)
```

Comment: Why use shell commands for this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob exists...

Comment: @AKX just linked the reason above, by the way the problem here is related to this specific script I guess, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you're getting an EPIPE (broken pipe) from the `head` process, since it terminates once it's read the requisite number of files.

I don't see a reason for using `head` though; better keep track of the file count in your Node code.

Here's my take on things – note it doesn't keep track of the filenames it's found by itself; that's on the `fileCallback` to do. That callback must return something truthy if it considers the file as something to count against the `limit`.

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

function findFiles(
  rootPath,
  findParams,
  limit = 0,
  fileCallback = () => true,
) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Files found so far.
    let nFound = 0;

    // Whether we killed `find` on our own (limit reached).
    let killed = false;

    // Buffer to hold our results so far.
    let buffer = Buffer.alloc(0);

    // Build args for `find`. Note `-print0` to delimit the files
    // with NUL bytes for extra safety (i.e. this can handle filenames
    // with newlines).
    const args = [rootPath].concat(findParams).concat("-print0");

    // Spawn the find process.
    const findProc = spawn("/usr/bin/find", args, { stdio: "pipe" });

    // Figure out what to do when the process exits; this may be
    // because it's done, or because we've closed things down upon
    // finding `limit` files.
    findProc.on("close", (code, signal) => {
      if (code && code !== 0) {
        return reject("find died with error " + code);
      }
      if (!killed && signal) {
        return reject("find died from signal " + signal);
      }
      resolve(nFound);
    });

    findProc.stdout.on("data", chunk => {
      // Concatenate the new chunk of data into the buffer.
      buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, chunk]);

      // Split the buffer; see below.
      let searchOffset = 0;
      for (;;) {
        // Find the next zero byte (which delimits files).
        const nextOffset = buffer.indexOf(0, searchOffset);
        // If there is none, we're done -- the rest of the buffer
        // is the start of a new filename, if any.
        if (nextOffset === -1) {
          break;
        }
        // Stringify the segment between `searchOffset` and `nextOffset`...
        const filename = buffer.toString("utf8", searchOffset, nextOffset);

        // ... pass it to the callback to see if it's valid...
        if (fileCallback(filename)) {
          nFound++;
          // ... see if we need to stop iterating over files...
          if (limit > 0 && nFound >= limit) {
            killed = true;
            findProc.kill();
            break;
          }
        }
        // and move on to the byte after the NUL.
        searchOffset = nextOffset + 1;
      }

      // Cut off the already-walked start of the buffer, if any.
      if (searchOffset > 0) {
        buffer = buffer.slice(searchOffset);
      }
    });
  });
}

findFiles("/Users/akx", ["-type", "f"], 1000, path => {
  console.log(path);
  return true;
}).then(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  },
  err => {
    throw new Error(err);
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Basically I was using `head` because of poor performances when have tons of files, but with the process `kill` approach it should behave better since you are only running the `find` command of course.

Comment: Sidenote: the guard here `if (limit > 0 && nFound >= limit - 1 ) {` to take in account of `nFound` increments at top.